# Can a report be run on SSRS and not show up in the Execution Log?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssms

I was wondering if one (any) of my users can run a report I have set up on SSRS and it not be captured in the execution log or anywhere for that matter?

I ask because I can see when I run a report and I see some other users running reports I have built.  I've built reports that hit the execution log and catalog and don't see them.

I'm curious because I've reached out to folks and they "say" they are using reports and have used them.  Yet, only the reports I'm running show up?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your username used in the connection string for the data source?

Comment: I think it is coming down too, no one is really running the reports.  In the connection string for the data source we use a general SSRS_User ID and Password.    But even that doesn't show up as being "used" to run reports.  So, it's not like i'm not seeing individuals, and seeing this one account.  I'm not seeing anyone

Comment: It seems like they aren't using the reports. Could you get a user run a report on one of their machines in your presence and then check the log? It would prove/disprove there is an issue. Also, this may be a silly question, are you sure you are checking the execution log for the correct instance of SSRS?

Comment: You are correct.  I did that on Friday.  I had a lady run some reports that she had alleged to using before.  They all showed up...   Not a silly question, yes I am checking the log.  I triple checked :)